# How to alter the memory usage formula in mongoDB so it uses more RAM?

Tags: database, mongodb, server

I have a server that has 32GB of RAM and based on the formula mongoDB utilizes 50%*(32-1) of the RAM and it is approximately 14 to 15 GB(after checking it with the top command). What I want to know is if there is any way in the /etc/mongod.conf to tell mongoDB to use more than 15 GB i.e 20GB. Or can it be a configuration in the mongo shell that allows to use more RAM. Or maybe it exists some kind of configuration that during the execution of a query mongoDB uses more RAM during the process and after the query is done it goes back to normal RAM usage based on the formula. The mongoDb service is configured in a ubuntu server.

Comment: Configuring software that somebody else wrote is generally off-topic here. There's a bit of a grey area: if "during the execution of a query mongoDB uses more RAM" applies to a query in software you wrote, it could be on-topic.

Comment: @MSalters Yes of course, I am not saying to configure the software by my myself, I just want to know if MongoDB has an option that can be enabled to make this question possible.

Comment: Have a look at [storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks a lot man this was the configuration I was looking for